# How to make the text following text Bold?

Tags: html

So I was adding the blinking text widget in the sidebar of my website.

I am using the following code to do it,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Blink Text using JavaScript</title></style>
    <script language="javascript">
        setInterval(blinktext, 500);
        var txt = "";
        var count = 0;
        function blinktext() {
            var cntrl = document.getElementById("txtblinkingtext");
            if (count == 0)
                txt = cntrl.value;
            if (count % 2 == 0)
                cntrl.value = "";
            else
                cntrl.value = txt;
            count++;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">
        <input type="text" id="txtblinkingtext" name="txtblinkingtext" value="NEWS STREAM" 
            readonly="readonly" style="height: 20px; width: 300px; background-color: #E64946;
            color: White; border: 0px none; text-align: center;">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just wanted to know how to use Bold or Strong method on "NEWS STREAM" text value

Answer (score 0):

You have a `</style>` tag hanging, remove it.

In your input style, add `font-weight:bold`. But, you'd rather have a CSS file with that rather than style in the HTML like this, it's not too pretty.